# Show a page with child Terms when parent Term clicked in block?

Tags: views

I want to Display child terms when a parent Term is clicked with Views in Drupal 7.
         Example

```
     Parent1
          .child11
          .child12

      Parent2
          .child21
          .child22
          .child23
```

So when Parent1 page is Visited, i will display the content of parent1 but with a block showing

```
          .child11 
          .child12
```

Any insight in Achieving this will be Appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: are you using D7 or D6?

Comment: Drupal 7, i have edited the Question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Views tree](http://drupal.org/project/views_tree%20module) module. It is great for taxonomy trees.

> This module provides a tree-based style plugin for Views. It is equivalent to the tree-based style template from Views 1.
>
> It is based off of the list style. Although it generates a nested view, there is still only a single query run for the view making it quite performant.

There is also a patch for adding collapsible support but I'm not sure how complete it is. See http://drupal.org/node/1538414

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the [Taxonomy menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module, it will exactly match your requirement. More details from the module's project page:

> - Custom Menu per vocabulary
> - Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths
> - Integrate with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)
> - Integrate with [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto): use URL/path aliases
> - Does not interfere with other menu modules

See the demo http://taxonomymenu.davidstoline.com/ (click the terms and you can see the term highlighted in the block)

Hope it will help you!